# How to find the max value without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, correlated-subquery

To get the below result set I wrote following SQL:

[image: Result Set]

```
SELECT  t1.FilmName,
        t2.CountryName,
        t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes
FROM Film as t1
INNER JOIN country as t2 on t1.FilmCountryId = t2.CountryID
WHERE t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes = ( SELECT max(t2.FilmRunTimeMinutes) 
                                FROM film as t2 
                                WHERE t2.FilmCountryId = t1.FilmCountryId 
                              )
ORDER BY FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC
```

I read this [Link](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/) and tried the same method but I could not. So how can I get the same result set using by `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

**Film** table has those columns:

```
FilmId --PK
FilmName 
FilmCountryId --FK
FilmRunTimeMinutes
```

**Country** table has those columns:

```
CountryId --PK
CountryName
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `Row_Number` window function

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties t1.FilmName,
                       t2.CountryName,
                       t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes
FROM   Film AS t1
       INNER JOIN country AS t2
               ON t1.FilmCountryId = t2.CountryID
ORDER  BY Row_number() OVER(partition BY FilmCountryId ORDER BY FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC),
          FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC;
```

or use `CTE/Sub-Select`

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT t1.FilmName,
                t2.CountryName,
                t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes,
                Rn = Row_number() OVER(partition BY FilmCountryId ORDER BY FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC)
         FROM   Film AS t1
                INNER JOIN country AS t2
                        ON t1.FilmCountryId = t2.CountryID)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  Rn = 1
ORDER  BY FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC
```

if you really want `left join` approach then

```
SELECT t1.FilmName,
       t2.CountryName,
       t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes
FROM   Film AS t1
       INNER JOIN country AS t2
               ON t1.FilmCountryId = t2.CountryID
       LEFT JOIN Film AS t3
              ON t3.FilmCountryId = t2.CountryID
                 AND t3.FilmRunTimeMinutes > t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes
WHERE  t3.FilmID IS NULL
ORDER  BY FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually  I used these methods as well. I just want to know LEFT OUTER JOIN method. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no FilmRunTimeMinutes column in Country table. Film table has FilmRuntimeMinutes column.

Comment: @aprkturk - You should be able to fix it.. anyway updated.. replace `filmid` with primary key column of `Film` table..

Comment: If you use the PK of Film table, query is executing for all the Film.

Comment: @aprkturk - of course..  so was your original query

Comment: @aprkturk- ok good I see the columns now but whats your expectation man ?

Comment: My query is show 8 record. Please look this pic  https://image.ibb.co/hTvEcR/Pic.png  but your query run for all the record. I just get the same result using by Left Outer Join method. Thank you

Comment: @aprkturk are you sure that condition looks like this `t3.FilmRunTimeMinutes > t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes` in left join

Comment: Yes, please see this pic. https://image.ibb.co/g7scE6/4.png This is your query's result. As u see there is more than one record for the "same country"

Comment: @aprkturk - check now.. Also add sample data and expected result in question

Comment: Still the same result.. Unfortunately I can not add sample data right now. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
;WITH Q
AS
(
    SELECT
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.FilmCountryId ORDER BY t2.FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC),
        t1.FilmName,
        t2.CountryName,
        t1.FilmRunTimeMinutes
    FROM Film as t1
    INNER JOIN country as t2 on t1.FilmCountryId=t2.CountryID
    ORDER BY FilmRunTimeMinutes DESC
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM Q
        WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Downvoted.  CTEs are a type of subquery so this does not answer the question.

Comment: OK it is a subquery but I think this is the best approach.  +1