# Get records from a SQL table for max date without subquery

Tags: sql, join

This is how my table looks like

[image]

I want to pull the records only having max date, however, without using subquery:
[image]

SQL experts pls help

Comment: [you can check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48240619/14870617)

Comment: try `SELECT t1.* FROM mytable t1 JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name GROUP BY t1.id HAVING t1.Date = MAX(t2.Date) AND t1.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM mytable);`

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL "[...] without using subquery"

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different possibilibtes.)

Comment: BTW, tables have _rows_, not records.

Comment: Why the _without using subquery_ requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I know you said: "[...] without using subquery", but EXISTS subquery is very powerfull and even Oracle himself recmmends use it.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table yt1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM your_table yt2 WHERE yt2.date > yt1.date
)
```